# Copy worksheet contents into a new Excel file

Tags: excel, vba

I create the new file but it empty with a Sheet1 (2).

I want to copy all contents of Sheet1 from the old file to Sheet1 of the new file.

```vb
Sub saveResult()
Dim mywb As Workbook
Dim Save_Path As String
Dim sht As Worksheet

Set sht = Worksheets("Macro")
Save_Path = sht.Cells(5, 7).Value

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = False

todayyear = Format(Date, "YYYY")
filemonth = Format(Date, "mm")
fileyear = Right(todayyear, 2)

Set mywb = Workbooks.Add
    Sheets("Sheet1").Copy Before:=mywb.Sheets("Sheet1")
    mywb.SaveAs Save_Path & "\FinalProduct " & filemonth & fileyear & ".xlsx"
   
mywb.Close SaveChanges:=False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = False

MsgBox ("Updated File Generated! Ready for review and upload.")
   
End Sub
```

Comment: `Sheets("Sheet1").Copy` ... you need to explicitly state the `Workbook` for `Sheets("Sheet1")`. You should also specify the `Workbook` for `Worksheets("Macro")`. That might be `ThisWorkbook`?

Comment: @BigBen I had tried that before but still came up with the same issue.  Is the syntax for that just: ` Set thiswb = ThisWorkbook

Set mywb = Workbooks.Add
    thiswb.Sheets("Sheet1").Copy Before:=mywb.Sheets("Sheet1")
    mywb.SaveAs Save_Path & "\FinalProduct " & filemonth & fileyear & ".xlsx"
`

Comment: Yes, or  just `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Copy`, no need for a `Workbook` variable.

Comment: I just updated to do this but it is still just blank.  Does it matter that I am copying it after I `set mywb = Workbooks.add`?

Comment: Btw you don't actually need to call `Workbooks.Add`. See the end of the posted answer.

Answer (score 1):

Best practice is to specify the parent `Workbook` for any `Worksheet`.

```
Set mywb = Workbooks.Add
Sheets("Sheet1").Copy ...
```

is implicitly

```
Set myWb = Workbooks.Add
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Copy ...
```

and since `Workbooks.Add` activates the new workbook, this is equivalent to

```
Set myWb = Workbooks.Add
myWb.Sheets("Sheet1").Copy ...
```

which copies a blank sheet.

---

Even better, `Worksheet.Copy` without any parameters creates a new workbook, so replace

```
Set mywb = Workbooks.Add
    Sheets("Sheet1").Copy Before:=mywb.Sheets("Sheet1")
    mywb.SaveAs Save_Path & "\FinalProduct " & filemonth & fileyear & ".xlsx"
```

with

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Copy
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Save_Path & "\FinalProduct " & filemonth & fileyear & ".xlsx"
```

Comment: That is the Microsoft suggested method, but I still like to `Add` a workbook first, to ensure I can reference it without being forced to use `ActiveWorkbook`. OPs method looks right to me, except for the missing workbook reference you pointed out.

Comment: @CLR yeah referencing the `ActiveWorkbook` is cringey, but the flip side is having to delete any blank sheets from the `Add`ed workbook, as you're well aware. Up to OP I guess.

Answer (score 0):

I've modified your code to fix the issue. I've also renamed some of your objects to make it easier to follow:

```
Sub saveResult()

    ' declarations
    Dim wbSource As Workbook, wsSource As Worksheet
    Dim wbDestination As Workbook, wsDestination As Worksheet
    Dim Save_Path As String
    
    ' set source
    Set wbSource = ActiveWorkbook
    Set wsSource = wbSource.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    
    ' read save path from Macro sheet
    Save_Path = wbSource.Worksheets("Macro").Cells(5, 7).Value
    
    ' dates for filename
    todayyear = Format(Date, "YYYY")
    filemonth = Format(Date, "mm")
    fileyear = Right(todayyear, 2)
    
    ' disable things
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    
    ' create new workbook
    Set wbDestination = Workbooks.Add
    
    ' copy wsSource to wbDestination, before first sheet, making it first sheet
    wsSource.Copy Before:=wbDestination.Sheets(1)
    
    ' remove all sheets in wbDestination other than copied sheet
    For Each ws In wbDestination.Worksheets
        If ws.Index > 1 Then ws.Delete
    Next
    
    ' rename remaining sheet
    wbDestination.Sheets(1).Name = "Sheet1"
    
    ' save wbDestination
    wbDestination.SaveAs Save_Path & "\FinalProduct " & filemonth & fileyear & ".xlsx"
    wbDestination.Close SaveChanges:=False
    
    ' enable things
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = False '<< did you mean True?
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    
    ' alert user
    MsgBox ("Updated File Generated! Ready for review and upload.")
       
End Sub
```